# Concatenate strings across columns that are not null

Tags: python, pandas

Wanting to do something similar to this, but complete row aggregation even when nulls are present without including them.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data= {'Subject': ['X', 'G', 'H', 'M'],
                         'Col1': ['cat', 'dog', np.nan, 'horse'],
                         'Col2': [np.nan, 'black', 'brown', 'grey'],
                         'Col3': ['small', 'medium', 'large', 'large']})

df['Col4'] = df['Col1'] + ', ' + df['Col2'] + ', ' + df['Col3']
```

For clarification, this is the resulting dataframe I am looking for

```
  Subject   Col1   Col2    Col3                Col4
0       X    cat    NaN   small          cat, small
1       G    dog  black  medium  dog, black, medium
2       H    NaN  brown   large        brown, large
3       M  horse   grey   large  horse, grey, large
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use `apply`, `dropna` and `join` to the column axis:

```
df['Col4'] = df[['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
```

It gives as expected:

```
  Subject   Col1   Col2    Col3              Col4
0       X    cat    NaN   small         cat,small
1       G    dog  black  medium  dog,black,medium
2       H    NaN  brown   large       brown,large
3       M  horse   grey   large  horse,grey,large
```

It should be more or less 30% faster than @yatu's way for small dataframes like this one, but the other way is better for larger ones.

Comment: Oh nice, I'm not sure why I hadn't thought about this. Thank you :)

Comment: It doesn't scale as well though (see [timings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60725004/9698684))

Comment: @yatu: You are right. I only tried timeit with OP's data and did not control how it would scale. I have warned future readers of it in the post.

Answer (score 5):

One approach is to [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) (which will remove missing values), [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on the first level, and aggregate with `str.join`:

```
df['Col4'] = (df.set_index('Subject')
                .stack()
                .groupby(level=0, sort=False)
                .agg(', '.join)
                .values)

print(df)

  Subject   Col1   Col2    Col3                Col4
0       X    cat    NaN   small          cat, small
1       G    dog  black  medium  dog, black, medium
2       H    NaN  brown   large        brown, large
3       M  horse   grey   large  horse, grey, large
```

Timings -

```
df_ = pd.concat([df]*1000, axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)

%timeit df_[['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
# 743 ms ± 17.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit (df_.set_index('Subject').stack().groupby(level=0, sort=False).agg(', '.join).values)
# 5.73 ms ± 168 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarity on this, @yatu. I have selected Serge's answer based on it's simplicity and performance on my particular data set. Keeping yours in reference for the future if this ever changes. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @yatu, could you help to explain this solution a little? why was "Subject" selected for set_index and what if I only want to join Col1 and Col3 but not Col3?